# In iOS, is it possible to start region based geofencing at a particular time?

Tags: ios, geofencing

My iOS app (which targets iOS 8.1+) use location services to determine if a user has entered a particular region during an event.  Ideally I would like to enable the geofencing a little before the event and turn it off a little after the event completes.  The problem is there is no guarantee the app is running an hour before the event so I turn on geofencing at the point the user registers for the event.  This is not the best approach as it means the geofencing is on for much longer than it needs to be.

As far as I can tell, there is no way to "wake up" the app in the background at a scheduled time in iOS.  I could use the push notification meant for updating content, but It's not clear to me if Apple would reject such a misuse of that notification.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking into this myself.

If you can arrange a push notification from your backend ("Silent push notification", aka "content-available"), it seems to be a good option. In real-world situations, this seems to give you the best control over the timing.  Unfortunately, it won't work if the person doesn't have connectivity.  Also, unfortunately, you need a backend that can queue events at a time (not just in response to an input.)  If you have such a backend already, and your app is only useful to the user when they have network coverage anyway, this is probably the best option. It seems this an appropriate use of the technology, so Apple should approve.

Another option I'm trying is to use background fetch. You specify a "minimum interval" to avoid too much fetching. Try 50% of the remaining time-to-event as a minimum. Every time the app wakes up (whether in the foreground because the user opened it, or in the background because background-fetch opens it) you can calculate the time-to-next-event, update the fetch interval, or start the region monitoring. You are supposed to use "background fetch" to fetch information from a server, but there doesn't seem to be any requirement to poll a server, you could poll your internal data instead. I haven't fully tested this yet but it seems promising.

You can use significant location change monitoring, which I've read will wake up your app briefly every 15 minutes or less, and you can use the time/location information to decide whether to turn on the geofence. I think this would work well in combination with the above "background fetch": Many hours or days before the event you rely on background fetch, which you then use to turn on significant location change monitoring a few hours before the event.  (There's speculation that geofencing is actually more battery efficient than significant change monitoring, but you could choose to assume that other apps on the user's device will already by watching for significant changes, in which case the marginal cost of your app adding itself to the list should be minimal.)

Putting them all together, you could create a sequence of

```
background fetch -> significant location monitoring ->  geofencing
```

as the time gets closer.

There is also the CLVisit monitoring functionality, it's not understood very well, but supposedly uses less power and is called less frequently than significant location change monitoring.  If the background fetch or silent remote notifications aren't working to wake up your app, give this a try, and please report back!

You can't (yet) do a silent content-available local notification (AFAICT). However, perhaps you can schedule up a local notification "Your event starts tomorrow" or something that convinces the user to click the option that starts the geofence.  Here's a tutorial on it http://www.appcoda.com/local-notifications-ios8/, the response of action can be UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Background so your geofence can come on (if the user responds to the notification) without bringing the app to the foreground.

It's been 5 to 6 weeks since you asked, do you have your own answer already?  Please let me know.

Comment: Have you implemented the solution inside an app?

Comment: Yes, @Sulabh.  I primarily rely on CLVisit monitoring.  As long as the person is moving around your app will get woken regularly with CLVisit monitoring.  Your app will get woken up when they leave their last location, and then if the event is close in distance or time, you could turn on geofencing. (Turn on background fetch, too, for the users with big iPads who don't carry their device around all the time, but background fetch might not get called often if the user doesn't use your app much, it's designed to refresh in anticipation them opening your app.)